# Rendering Underscore variables in Jade

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, pug, scalate

I have included the assets described in [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528885/using-jade-templates-in-backbone-js), and the Underscore variables work except when inside tags. I can not get variables to render inside dynamic tags `data-id=someid`for doing things `onClick` with Backbone events.

In standard HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="template-action1-thing">
<tr>
   <td class="action-td" style="width: 10%;">
      <button id="do-remove" data-id="<%= obj.id %>">X</button>             
   </td>
</tr>
</script>
```

With (Scalate) Jade, which doesn't work:

```
script(id='template-action1-thing' type='text/template')
  p <%= obj.id %> Will render
  tr
    td.action-td(style='width: 10%;')
      button(id='do-remove' data-id='<%= obj.id %>') 
        | X
```

If I do [this](https://gist.github.com/1886215), the **actual html** renders with the variable properly, though incorrectly:

```
tr td(style='width: 10%;') button(id='do-remove_thing' data-id='myid') X
```

With a template like:

```
script(id='template-action1-thing' type='text/template')
  |   td.action-td(style='width: 10%;')
  |     button(id='do-remove_thing' data-id='<%= obj.id %>') X
```

Comment: Try adding a `|` to beginning of every line in your template as [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1886215) seems to suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use an underscore template in jade you need change to template to look like this:

```
script(id='template-action1-thing' type='text/template')
  | <tr>
  |   <td class="action-td" style="width: 10%;">
  |     <button id="do-remove" data-id="<%= obj.id %>">X</button>             
  |   </td>
  | </tr>
```

Or you could look at using [jade templates](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#includes) instead of underscore templates.

Comment: Oh, _standard_ HTML. Got it!

Answer (score 11):

I know this question has already been answered, but in searching for a more eloquent solution, I found that this also works:

```
script(type='text/html', id='tpl-name')
  h3!='<%= foo %>'
  p!='<%= bar %>'
```

This allows you to keep using Jade syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Now we can use `script.` to insert a block of plain text as described here: http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/.

```
script(id='template-action1-thing' type='text/template').
    <tr>
       <td class="action-td" style="width: 10%;">
          <button id="do-remove" data-id="<%= obj.id %>">X</button>             
       </td>
    </tr>
```